# Java SE 6 cannot be seen

Tags: java, glassfish

I installed Java SE 6 from oracle

but, on the commant prompt, I get this error when trying to send any command :

```
Glassfish requieres JAVA SE 6, your JDK is version 0
```

is there anything i can do to make this work, I also installed version 10 but nothing works of these two

It's like it cannot see it at all

OS: Windows 64x

JAVA SE VER. : downloaded it from here : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html

Command: asadmin create-domain --adminport 4848 --instanceport 8080 name

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-fix-the-GlassFish-requires-Java-SE-version-6-Your-JDK-is-version-0-problem

Comment: Can you give some more specific details about your system (including OS), the version of Java6, the command that is triggering this error, etc.

Comment: @rwp  updated the question

Comment: @rwp do u think i downloaded the wrong file? it's jdk-6u45

Answer (score 0):

Glassfish should only require one or two environment variables, and one path.

JAVA_HOME should point to the directory where the jdk bin directory lives.
JRE_Home should point to the directory where the jre's bin directory lives.
PATH should include %JAVA_HOME%\bin;

If those are set correctly, you should be able to open a command prompt and type

```
java -version
```

and get a satisfactory response.

Comment: it says 1.7.0, while i have version 6 installed. how can i let it see it? and now when i write the command it says the system cannot find specified path

Comment: can you please explain what do you mean by java_home, i just installed java se 6 and i'm writing commands, anything else i need to do before?

Comment: this path: C:\>cd \opt\glassfish3\bin